fetching data from 2 10M+ rows tables
I need to run the following query on my production database, using 2 tables that contain more than 10M rows each :
SELECT rm.parent_id as processed_media_id
FROM render_medias rm
JOIN processed_medias pm ON pm.id = rm.parent_id
WHERE rm.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(rm.id) AS id
    FROM render_medias rm
    WHERE rm.parent_type = 'App\\Models\\ProjectMedia'
    AND rm.deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY rm.parent_id
)
AND rm.parent_type = 'App\\Models\\ProjectMedia'
AND (JSON_VALUE(rm.data, '$.keepSize') = 'blur' or JSON_VALUE(rm.data, '$.legacyKeepSize') = 'true')
AND pm.transformations IS NULL

Right now, the query is going timeout.
Here is the EXPLAIN output :
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                             | key                                       | key_len | ref                  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pm    | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY                                                                   | NULL                                      | NULL    | NULL                 | 22595880 |    10.00 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | rm    | NULL       | ref  | render_medias_parent_type_parent_id_index,render_medias_parent_type_index | render_medias_parent_type_parent_id_index | 5       | const,playplay.pm.id |        1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | rm    | NULL       | ref  | render_medias_parent_type_parent_id_index,render_medias_parent_type_index | render_medias_parent_type_parent_id_index | 1       | const                | 13642578 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0,02 sec)

Is there something I can optimize to make it usable ?
here is the description of the 2 related tables :
CREATE TABLE `render_medias` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_type` enum('App\\Models\\ProjectMedia','App\\Models\\RawMediaV2') COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('to_process','processing','processed','errored','canceled') COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `folder` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `rendered_url` text COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci,
  `thumbnail_url` text COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci,
  `to_queue_data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `render_duplicated_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `launched_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rendered_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_metadata` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `urls` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `normalized_file_metadata` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `render_medias_render_duplicated_id_foreign` (`render_duplicated_id`),
  KEY `render_medias_parent_type_parent_id_index` (`parent_type`,`parent_id`),
  KEY `render_medias_status_index` (`status`),
  KEY `render_medias_parent_type_index` (`parent_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `render_medias_render_duplicated_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`render_duplicated_id`) REFERENCES `render_medias` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45691332 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `processed_medias` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw_media_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filter_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `speed_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` enum('pexels','tenor','upload','storyblocks','getty','getty_edito','unsplash','giphy','favorites','recently_used','library','option_list','music_list') COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_render_media_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `transformations` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `project_medias_project_id_foreign` (`project_id`),
  KEY `project_medias_raw_media_v2_id_foreign` (`raw_media_id`),
  KEY `project_medias_relation_type_index` (`relation_type`),
  KEY `processed_medias_filter_id_foreign` (`filter_id`),
  KEY `processed_medias_last_render_media_id_foreign` (`last_render_media_id`),
  KEY `processed_medias_speed_id_foreign` (`speed_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `processed_medias_filter_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`filter_id`) REFERENCES `processed_medias_filters` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `processed_medias_last_render_media_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`last_render_media_id`) REFERENCES `render_medias` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `processed_medias_speed_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`speed_id`) REFERENCES `processed_medias_speeds` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `project_medias_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `project_medias_raw_media_v2_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`raw_media_id`) REFERENCES `raw_medias` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25564774 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_unicode_ci;


Which database system...MySQL?

It may be faster to use a window function rather than a self-join.
SELECT rm.parent_id as processed_media_id
FROM (
    SELECT rm.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rm.parent_id ORDER BY rm.id DESC) AS rn
    FROM render_medias rm
    WHERE rm.parent_type = 'App\\Models\\ProjectMedia'
      AND rm.deleted_at IS NULL
) rm
JOIN processed_medias pm ON pm.id = rm.parent_id
WHERE rm.rn = 1
  AND (JSON_VALUE(rm.data, '$.keepSize') = 'blur' OR JSON_VALUE(rm.data, '$.legacyKeepSize') = 'true')
  AND pm.transformations IS NULL;

You may want to push the JSON_VALUE predicates into the subquery, but that may change semantics.
